# When was the Spear of Destiny used for the first time as a plot device?

Tags: history-of

I remember an episode from the 1997 TV series *Roar* featuring a young Heath Ledger where the Spear of Destiny, also known as the Holy Lance or the Lance of Longinus, appeared as a plot device, but I ask: when was this legendary lance, that pierced the side of Jesus as he hung on the cross, first used as a plot device (not as a MacGuffin)?

[image: Conor (Heath Ledger and the Spear of Destiny]

Comment: There is [Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Wagner)'s opera _[Parsifal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsifal)_ where the Spear drives the plot.  This is mentioned in the Wikipedia article on the [Holy Lance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Lance).

Comment: Would you accept the Bible?

Comment: @Azor that’s what I was thinking :P

Comment: Off-topic because this, as currently written, includes religious works, which are off-topic.

Comment: As written, the correct answer is pretty clearly a religious text involving the crucifixion (one version of the bible or another, or possibly any number of apocryphal texts) as this is the genesis of the Spear, and thus off-topic, as Stormblessed points out. If you tweaked it to ask what non-religious text SciFi/Fantasy work it appeared in, it might be more viable.  Otherwise you run into the 'Your Religion is Fantasy to Me' issue which is part of why they are off topic. Those get.. ugly.

Comment: @K-H-W The term "plot device" limits the question to literature already.

Comment: Good question! I recall first hearing about the "Spear of Destiny" when the Castle Wolfenstein prequel came out in 1992. At the time it was pretty obscure; now it seems to be an inevitable part of almost every modern-era paranormal story. However, I only recall it being invoked as a tool needed to kill or save someone or something. Do you have an example of it being merely invoked as a MacGuffin?

Comment: @jeffronicus - Half season 2 of CW fantasy/sci-fi TV series DC's Legends of Tomorrow centers around the "Spear of Destiny" as a MacGuffin.

Comment: @Bingo But a MacGuffin is an inert object that's merely an incitement to action, like the Maltese Falcon or the briefcase in Pulp Fiction. In "Legends of Tomorrow," the Spear actually has reality-warping powers that affect the plot. That's why I'm asking if the Spear has been included as basically just a tchotchke.

Comment: @Spencer - True, but that's where it gets ugly.  A religion (especially an obscure or secretive one) that is not taken seriously by one person may be considered literature to another - and that directly leads to unpleasantness.  Hence my suggestion to be overly clear -- perhaps it should be assumed based on the term plot device.. But many stories of many religions have been gone over enough times that they sure seem to follow the standard story-telling tropes, including plot-devices and other literary tools.  (I won't try to list them, for obvious reasons, but they are easy to find.)

Comment: @jeffronicus - I do not like to enter in a disjunctive here about the ‘macguffiness’ of DC' LOT Spear if Destiny. To me, it is a MacGuffing that only triggers the plot just like the venerable Indiana's Ark.Regarding the spear as  a tchotchke, I don't remember.

Comment: @K-H-W You're overthinking something that's simple.

Comment: @Spencer - No, not really -- I'm attempting to facilitate a good answer based on quite a bit of experience watching how these can go awry.  That said, Comments aren't really a place for this discussion; if you would like to continue, I'll be happy to chat with you via Chat.

Answer (score 7):

The literary use of the Spear of Destiny or "[Holy Lance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Lance)" is inextricably tied up with Arthurian legend and especially the Holy Grail, but it took until the 19th Century to be called the Spear that pierced Jesus's side.

The unfinished 11th century French romantic poem *[Perceval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceval,_the_Story_of_the_Grail)* by [Chretien de Troyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chr%C3%A9tien_de_Troyes) use a lance and a grail as plot devices, but neither is "holy".

Percival is at a banquet at the castle of the [Fisher King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_King), who has a wound that does not heal. Various items such as candelabra and a bleeding lance. He sees a serving-bowl or "grail" carried back and forth by a young woman. He is curious but is too polite to ask anything.

Perceval is later told that his reticence at the banquet was a moral failure: Had he asked "Whom does the Grail Serve?" the Fisher-King would have been healed of his wound.

This story was retold by 13th century poet [Wolfram von Eschenbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_von_Eschenbach) in his poem *[Parzival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parzival)* where the grail becomes the Holy Grail.

The lance finally appears in its modern form in [Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Wagner)'s opera *[Parsifal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsifal)*, where the Spear becomes the key to the fulfillment of the Grail quest.

The knight Amfortas had been given the Grail and the Spear to guard, but it was stolen from him, the thief Klingsor stabbing Amfortas with it. The wound does not heal and can only be healed by the Spear.

As part of the Quest for the Grail, Parsifal <s>disarms Klingsor and the Spear changes allegiance</s> gets the Spear from Klingsor when he throws it at Parsifal and it refuses to kill the virtuous knight.

At the end, Parsifal heals Amfortas with the Spear and allows Parsifal to reveal the Grail.